# Problem doing some Integration Test with test Cointainers

Tags: java, project-reactor, localstack

I'm having some problems with these tests. Sometimes run as successful results and otherwise, it couldn't happened.

There is a problem with the verify lines, but I'm reseting the mock with the function @beforeEach

I'm not sure what is happening and I submitted the error and the integration test.

```
commandHandler.handle(
    <domain.ExtractRequestedDocumentsData>
);
Wanted 1 time:
-> at service.SqsMessagesConsumerIntegrationTest.lambda$givenRightSqsMessagesWhenConsumedThenQueueIsEmpty$0(SqsMessagesConsumerIntegrationTest.java:73)
But was 2 times:
-> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:132)
-> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:132)

org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
commandHandler.handle(
    <any com.loanlogics.dod.ade.splitter.domain.ExtractRequestedDocumentsData>
);
Wanted 1 time:
-> at .aws.service.SqsMessagesConsumerIntegrationTest.lambda$givenRightSqsMessagesWhenConsumedThenQueueIsEmpty$0(SqsMessagesConsumerIntegrationTest.java:73)
But was 2 times:
-> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:132)
-> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:132)
```

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.testcontainers.shaded.org.awaitility.Awaitility.await;

import com.loanlogics.dod.ade.splitter.domain.Command;
import com.loanlogics.dod.ade.splitter.domain.CommandHandler;
import com.loanlogics.dod.ade.splitter.domain.ExtractRequestedDocumentsData;
import com.loanlogics.dod.ade.splitter.infraestructure.aws.config.AwsConfig;
import com.loanlogics.dod.ade.splitter.infraestructure.aws.config.LocalStackAwsTestConfig;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.Message;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.SendMessageRequest;

class SqsMessagesConsumerIntegrationTest extends LocalStackAwsTestConfig {

  private static final String TEST_JSON_FILE_PATH = "test-json-message.json";
  //private final static String EXTRACTION_QUEUE_NAME = "test_adeSplitExtractionCommands.fifo";
  private final static String EXTRACTION_QUEUE_NAME = "test_adeSplitExtractionCommands";

  private static AwsConfig awsConfig = Mockito.mock(AwsConfig.class);
  private static CommandHandler commandHandler = Mockito.mock(CommandHandler.class);

  private static SqsMessagesConsumer sqsMessagesConsumer;
  private static String extractionQueueUrl;


  @BeforeAll
  public static void beforeAll() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    //this.createFifoQueue(EXTRACTION_QUEUE_NAME);
    extractionQueueUrl = createQueue(EXTRACTION_QUEUE_NAME);
    sqsMessagesConsumer = new SqsMessagesConsumer(sqsAsyncClient, awsConfig, commandHandler);
    sqsMessagesConsumer.consume(EXTRACTION_QUEUE_NAME);
  }

  @BeforeEach
  public void beforeEach() {
    Mockito.reset(commandHandler);
    Mockito.when(commandHandler.handle(any(Command.class))).thenReturn(Mono.just(new ExtractRequestedDocumentsData()).then());
    Mockito.when(awsConfig.getSqsQueueUrl()).thenReturn(extractionQueueUrl);
  }


  @Test
  void givenRightSqsMessagesWhenConsumedThenQueueIsEmpty() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
    String jsonContent = loadJsonFromFile();

    SendMessageRequest sendMessageRequest = SendMessageRequest.builder()
        .queueUrl(extractionQueueUrl)
        .messageBody(jsonContent)
        //.messageGroupId("1")
        .build();

    sqsAsyncClient.sendMessage(sendMessageRequest).get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    await().atMost(Duration.ofSeconds(15))
        .untilAsserted(() -> {
          verify(commandHandler, times(1)).handle(any(ExtractRequestedDocumentsData.class));
          assertEquals(0, getMessageCount(extractionQueueUrl));
        });
  }


  @Test
  void givenWrongSqsMessagesWhenConsumedThenQueueIsEmpty() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
    SendMessageRequest sendMessageRequest = SendMessageRequest.builder()
        .queueUrl(extractionQueueUrl)
        .messageBody("{}")
        .build();

    sqsAsyncClient.sendMessage(sendMessageRequest).get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    await().atMost(Duration.ofSeconds(15))
        .untilAsserted(() -> {
          verify(commandHandler, times(0)).handle(any(ExtractRequestedDocumentsData.class));
          assertEquals(0, getMessageCount(extractionQueueUrl));
        });
  }


  private int getMessageCount(String queueUrl) {
    List<Message> messages = sqsAsyncClient.receiveMessage(builder -> builder.queueUrl(queueUrl)).join().messages();
    return messages.size();
  }

  private static String loadJsonFromFile() {
    try {
      InputStream inputStream = SqsMessagesConsumerIntegrationTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(TEST_JSON_FILE_PATH);
      if (inputStream != null) {
        return new String(inputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("File not found: " + TEST_JSON_FILE_PATH);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

sucessfull result in the test always